# showing a basis is suitable for a dual space, from linear forms

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

> Let us define $B = b_1, b_2, b_3$; where $ b_1(f) = f(0)$, $ b_2(f)=−f'(0) $ and  $b_3(f) = f''(0) $.
>
> Let $E
> ^∗$ be the dual basis of $E = {1, x, x^2}$. Show that B is a basis of the dual space ($R[x]_2)^*$.

I understand its simple once I have the column vectors for the various $[b_i]_{E^*}$ , but i don't know how to begin to find those vectors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**

Let denote $B^*_c=(e^*_1,e^*_2,e^*_3)$ the dual  basis of $(1,x,x^2)$ then we have

$$b_1=\alpha_1e^*_1+\beta_1e^*_2+\gamma_1e^*_3$$
hence

$$b_1(1)=1=\alpha_1\quad;\quad b_1(x)=0=\beta_1\quad;\quad b_1(x^2)=0=\gamma$$
and do the same thing for the other vectors and you get  the column vectors for the various $[b_i]_{E^∗}$.